# No NullPointerException when calling an extension function on null reference

Tags: kotlin, null

I'm a bit puzzled as to why there's no `NullPointerException` thrown anywhere in this code:

```
fun main() {
   null.print()
}

fun <T> T.print() {
    this.let { println(it) }
}
```

There is no compiler warning nor exception when calling the extension function `print` over a `null` value, being it defined with a non-nullable receiver type, and no exception again when calling `let` over that `null` reference, even though `let` has a non-nullable reciever type also. What is the reason?

Comment: "defined with a non-nullable receiver type", no, `<T>` is the same as `<T : Any?>`, so receiver can be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For extension methods, kotlin provides a syntactic sugar. When you are calling the extension method, what kotlin does here is it provides wrapper on top; so that by using this you can get the instance of the caller. So when you call `null.print()`, it is basically calling `print(null)` underneath.

So you can think of the following function

```
fun <T> T.print()
```

converted to

```
fun <T> print(T t)
```

Same goes for let, it is an extension method which is actually passing the `null` parameter to `let` instead of calling `let` on `null` instance.

Please note that, I am new to kotlin, so any correction would be much appreciated.